# if statement in scriplets in jsp

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Extremely new to jsp. I have a servlet where I am setting some attributes. On the jsp page I just retrieve and print these. My jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.math.BigInteger" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Result Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
        String errorin = (String) request.getAttribute("errorinput");

         if (errorin.isEmpty()) { %>
    <% BigInteger number1= (BigInteger) request.getAttribute("num1");
        BigInteger number2= (BigInteger) request.getAttribute("num2");
        BigInteger number3= (BigInteger) request.getAttribute("num3"); %>

         Factors:  <%= number1 %> , <%= number2 %> , <%= number3 %>  
          <% } else{ %>
         <%= errorin %>
            <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

The error I get

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
```

NOTE: using c is not an option

Comment: Which container/version are you using? For example, Tomcat 8.5.43.

Comment: tomcat 8.5 is what I am using

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?  I cannot reproduce this error on Tomcat 8.5. Please tell us how to reproduce it.